# CSS Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling with creating horizontal scroll effect... I need to have 2 rows in my container that will scroll horizontally.

```css
.blocks-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  width: 16.6666%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-container">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dg01n7ve/

I have 3 rows and no scroll. And also I'd like to control horizontal scroll with vertical mouse wheel as shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/), but this tutorial is not helping me for 2 reasons: It's only one row and blocks are squares (mine will be rectangles). Can it be done without using any jQuery plugins etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this **CSS** Remove float left and add **display** in line.

```
.blocks-container { width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; }
.block { width: 16.6666%; height: 200px; background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #fff; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Ok, but this solution is not complete. I still have one row.

Comment: Send me your design screenshot.I'll be to design and send it to you.

Comment: No need, I already managed to achieve desired effect, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

if you can manage which item have to be displayed in first or second line, I suggest to use an inline-block display and setting overflow x & y like this :

```css
.blocks-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.block {
  width: 16.6666%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-container">
  <div class="firstLine">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondLine">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit : view snippet in full-screen for a real rendering